# Hibernate Save method practice

Tags: java, performance, thread-safety, hibernate

We are new into hibernate, in our project for saving an entry the below given code is used, please have a look.

```
public void save(Object obj) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (JDBCException jde) {
        logger.fatal("Error occured in database communication", jde);
        transaction.rollback();
        throw new RuntimeException(jde);
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do (Considering performance and Security) ? 
Is this thread safe? as there may be number of users at the same time.

Bonus Question:is there any way to make this code better in Java 8 ?

---

*ps:This method is written in our DatabaseUtil class.*

Answer (score 1):

Your `finally` should strive to be as safe as it can, since you may have already had some error occur. To that end, you could run into trouble with a null pointer:

```
} finally {
    if (session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

If session is `null` then you've just caused another error, so test `session` before you call on it:

```
} finally {
    if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
    }
}
```